Publish WFS/WMS in QGIS equivalent to ArcGIS Server
Is there an equivalent to ArcGIS Server, on which you can publish ArcGIS projects in e.g. WMS or WFS, a way to achieve this in QGIS without a plugin?
And if not, which plugin (except qgis2web, i tried that before) would work best, also with regard to municipal work?

QGIS Server https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/server_manual/index.html

I saw this guide before, but thank you anyway!
So that means that the server has to be set up completely manually in QGIS? In ArcGIS, I believe this is done via Enterprise?

You still need to provision a server then install and set up ArcGIS Enterprise/Server. It's not an automatic process

Or are you thinking of ArcGIS Online where someone does it all for you? In that case, look at QGIS Cloud
